# $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}})/\mathbb{Q}(2+\sqrt{2}) $ is cyclic?

Tags: galois-theory

my teacher said the extension 
$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}})/\mathbb{Q}(2+\sqrt{2}) $ has degree two. However, she said that this implies the quotient is cyclic. I dont understand why. I Know that since $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}): \mathbb{Q}(2+\sqrt{2})]=2,$ it is normal but I do not see how it implies cyclicity.

Answer (score 4):

The cardinality of the Galois group of a finite normal extension is the degree of the extension. The only group with two elements is $C_2$.